# Couldn't load an index structure called meta index

Tags: information-retrieval, inverted-index

when I use terrier 3.5 to build inverted index for the collection.
firstly,I use "./bin/trec_setup.sh var/corpus"
secondly,I use "./bin/trec_terrier.sh -i -j" but ter arise the error that Couldn't load an index structure called meta index.

```
Setting TERRIER_HOME to /home/mao/Desktop/terrier-3.5
INFO - TRECCollection read collection specification (1 files)
INFO - Processing var/collection/sogou/sogou
INFO - Structure meta reading lookup file into memory
INFO - Structure meta reading reverse map for key docno directly from disk
ERROR - Couldn't load an index structure called meta
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.terrier.structures.Index.loadIndexStructure(Index.java:421)
    at org.terrier.structures.Index.getIndexStructure(Index.java:330)
    at org.terrier.structures.Index.loadIndices(Index.java:252)
    at org.terrier.structures.Index.<init>(Index.java:189)
    at org.terrier.structures.Index.createIndex(Index.java:659)
    at org.terrier.applications.TRECIndexing.createSinglePass(TRECIndexing.java:204)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.run(TrecTerrier.java:382)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.applyOptions(TrecTerrier.java:564)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.main(TrecTerrier.java:235)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mao/Desktop/terrier-3.5/var/index/data.meta-0.fsomapfile (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:122)
    at org.terrier.utility.io.LocalFileSystem$LocalRandomAccessFile.<init>(LocalFileSystem.java:54)
    at org.terrier.utility.io.LocalFileSystem.openFileRandom(LocalFileSystem.java:116)
    at org.terrier.utility.Files.openFileRandom(Files.java:354)
    at org.terrier.structures.collections.FSOrderedMapFile.<init>(FSOrderedMapFile.java:571)
    at org.terrier.structures.CompressingMetaIndex.loadIndex(CompressingMetaIndex.java:1194)
    at org.terrier.structures.CompressingMetaIndex.<init>(CompressingMetaIndex.java:835)
    ... 13 more
A problem occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.terrier.applications.TRECIndexing.createSinglePass(TRECIndexing.java:205)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.run(TrecTerrier.java:382)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.applyOptions(TrecTerrier.java:564)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.main(TrecTerrier.java:235)
mao@ubuntu:~/Desktop/terrier-3.5$ ./bin/trec_terrier.sh --printmeta
Setting TERRIER_HOME to /home/mao/Desktop/terrier-3.5
ERROR - Couldn't load an index structure called meta-inputstream
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.terrier.structures.Index.loadIndexStructure(Index.java:421)
    at org.terrier.structures.Index.getIndexStructureInputStream(Index.java:449)
    at org.terrier.structures.IndexUtil.printMetaIndex(IndexUtil.java:328)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.run(TrecTerrier.java:412)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.applyOptions(TrecTerrier.java:564)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.main(TrecTerrier.java:235)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
    at org.terrier.structures.CompressingMetaIndex$InputStream.<init>(CompressingMetaIndex.java:702)
    at org.terrier.structures.CompressingMetaIndex$InputStream.<init>(CompressingMetaIndex.java:730)
    ... 10 more
A problem occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.terrier.structures.IndexUtil.printMetaIndex(IndexUtil.java:329)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.run(TrecTerrier.java:412)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.applyOptions(TrecTerrier.java:564)
    at org.terrier.applications.TrecTerrier.main(TrecTerrier.java:235)
```

Answer (score 0):

When this occurred to me, the reason for the error was that there was a corrupt index in the terrier folder, that was created because I ran indexing without running setup first.

**Delete all files from the var/index subfolder in Terrier home directory.**

Then it may work normally.